# Are Ubuntu One and AskUbuntu linked in anyway?

Tags: discussion

I'm logged into Ubuntu one. Is it possible to link my other accounts using my Ubuntu one login? I have several email and forum accounts and I wish to link all of them instead of having to login to each one every-time.

Comment: They only thing they have in common is that you can login with your USO (Ubuntu Single sign-On) (Launchpad account for example).

Comment: @UriHerrera I recommend posting that as an answer.