# Possible invalid move to meta

Tags: discussion, migration

I was looking at this question:

[Are Ubuntu One and AskUbuntu linked in anyway?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5485/are-ubuntu-one-and-askubuntu-linked-in-anyway)

and while I am not quite sure what the questions is about, the question isn't about askubuntu per se, is it? I mean, it doesn't seem a meta-question to me.The title could be interpreted as something about askUbuntu, sure, but the contents don't even mention the site?

I think it shouldn't have been migrated to meta, but it might need some cleaning up though?

Answer (score 6):

That's a good question, it was migrated by a vote from five other users, but it might be premature given the scant information provided by the OP. At this point I think the question is essentially "lost" the author hasn't been back to the site since they asked and closing it as NARQ might be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I thought It was about logging into Ask Ubuntu with a Ubuntu One account, and thus would be about the workings of the site.

Sure, linking other sites with Ubuntu One might work the same... but the title leads me to believe the first goal is about using Ubuntu One and AskUbuntu. Only time will tell...